# Sorting a NSArray

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nsarray

I have a *NSArray* of objects.
Those objects have an int attribute called "distance". I would like to sort my array by distance.

Could someone please tell me how to do that ? I can't understand how the *sortUsingSelector* or *sortUsingDescriptor* methods are working...

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I assume you're using an NSMutableArray, because an NSArray is immutable.

When you sort something, you want the end result to be arranged as

```
x1 <= x2 <= x3 <= x4 <= ... <= xN
```

How to define this `<=`? There are 3 solutions in ObjC.

---

### 1. `-sortUsingSelector:`

`[arr sortUsingSelector:@selector(foo:)]` means that its elements will be compared as*

```
x <= y      is equivalent to      [x foo:y] <= 0
```

For example, to sort a list of strings case-insensitively, you use `[arr sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]`.

---

### 2. `-sortUsingFunction:context:`

This is similar to `-sortUsingSelector:`, but it uses a function pointer as input. `[arr sortUsingFunction:funcptr context:ctx]` means that its elements will be compared as

```
x <= y      is equivalent to      funcptr(x, y, ctx) <= 0
```

---

### 3. `-sortUsingDescriptors:`

This is the most complicated one. It takes a list of NSSortDescriptors which describe the expected order of the properties. One basic example:

```
NSSortDescriptor* desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
[desc release];
```

the descriptor tells the sort routine to "sort by the key `distance` in ascending order".

Suppose there are 2 keys, integers `x` ascending then and strings `y` descending, then you may write

```
NSSortDescriptor* dx = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"x" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor* dy = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"y" ascending:NO selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil]];
[dx release];
[dy release];
```

and so on.

---

Note: * Actually you should only return -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: +1, except you don't return -1, 0, or 1.  You return `NSOrderedDescending`, `NSOrderedSame`, or `NSOrderedAscending`.

Comment: +1, except [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil]]; probably should be dx, dy as the objects passed to the array.

Comment: What if your array doesnt have distance property, only latitude and longitude and you have a method that calculates distance from userLocation to each lat/long coordinate.  What must I do to sort the array then?

Answer (score 3):

Finnaly I found out how to do that :

**after @implementation :**

```
static NSInteger sort(Myclass *obj1, Myclass *obj2, void *context) {

if(obj1.distance < obj2.distance)
return NSOrderedAscending;
else if(obj1.distance > obj2.distance)
return NSOrderedDescending;
else
return NSOrderedSame;
```

**Then wherever you need to sort your NSArray :**

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:sort context:NULL];
```