# NSArray sort with custom objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following class:

```
typedef enum eItems {
kItem1,
kItem2,
kItem3  
} MyItem;

@interface MyClass: CCSprite<CCTargetedTouchDelegate>{
... 
MyItem mClIt;
...
}

...
- (NSComparisonResult)MyCompareFunc:(MyClass*)inObject
- (MyItem)GetSomeItem;
...
```

And function for sorting:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)MyCompareFunc:(MyClass*)inObject
{
 if ([self GetSomeItem] > [inObject GetSomeItem])
    return NSOrderedDescending;
 else if ([self GetSomeItem] < [inObject GetSomeItem])
    return NSOrderedAscending;
 return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

I create the NSArray of the MyClass objects later in the some class:

```
@interface Person : Main {
    ....
    NSArray * mObjArr;
    ....
}
```

And I need to sort the mObjArr with help of MyCompareFunc, using  `sortUsingSelector:@selector(MyCompareFunc:)` method. But I have the following error:

> error: accessing unknown 'mObjArr'
>   getter method.

Help please to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is there a property declaration corresponding to the mObjArr instance variable? It seems that since you're getting an "unknown getter" method that the calling code is looking for a property that either isn't declared or isn't imported in the implementation file.

Comment: It might help to show the part of the code where the error is actually occuring.

Comment: Yes, I have no property, thanks. I've added the property for the mObjArr. But I still have the problem.
Programm crashes on line:
    [self.mObjArr sortUsingSelector:@selector(MyCompareFunc:)];

While compiling I have the warning on the line:
'NSArray' may not respond to '-sortUsingSelector:'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849911/sorting-a-nsarray

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but you'd need an NSMutableArray, not NSArray, to use `sortUsingSelector:`.