# How to sort an NSArray with objects

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

I have a `NSArray` of objects. Each object has several properties.

For example:
The `NSArray oneArray` has 5 objects. Each object has the following properties: `name`, `address`, `ZIP_Code`.

How can I sort the `NSArray`, by `name`?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849911/sorting-a-nsarray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor* dx = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor* dy = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"address" ascending:NO selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[arr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dx, dy, nil]];
[dx release];
[dy release];
```

Taken from code posted by KennyTM. Edited by Jordan to actually work ;) Replace Array arr with your array. Modify to suit.

Comment: +1 note that this only works if `arr` is an `NSMutableArray`.  If `arr` is an `NSArray`, then you have to use `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` and capture the return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSInteger nameSort(id obj1, id obj2, void *context)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [obj1.name compare:obj2.name];

        if (result == NSOrderedAscending) // stringOne < stringTwo
            return NSOrderedAscending;

        if (result == NSOrderedDescending) // stringOne > stringTwo
            return NSOrderedDecending;

        if (result == NSOrderedSame) // stringOne == stringTwo
            return NSOrderedSame;
    }
/*to sort oneArray*/ oneArray = [oneArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:nameSort context:NULL];
```

Comment: Those ifs are unnecessary, just return `result`.

Answer (score 1):

I like Jordan's answer because (1) I didn't know about NSSortDescriptor and (2) it's useful for sorting on multiple properties.

But what I usually do is create a method like `-(NSComparisionResult)compare:(MyClass*)otherObject` in my class, then use `-[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]`.  The compare method itself is similar to Jumhyn's answer, but I think is a little cleaner because the class itself compares the objects, instead of a stand-alone function.

Comment: +1 for your answer!
Your idea also great. This is similar to the Comparator in Java!