# Sorting is not working correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I am saving some files in document directory through my app using custom naming as "file1.format" ,"file2.format" and so on.Later I fetch these files in an Array and printing them in a loop then they are coming in sorted form but the problem arises when I store "file10.format"  and so on. After this the result comes is some what unexpected. As after saving 10th file the output comes like

file1.foramt
file10.format
file2.format
.
.
file6.format
file61.format
file7.format
I don't know why sorting take all 1s or 2s on one place as shown above while it is expected that 10 should just comes after 9 not after 1.I used all kind of sorting but the result is coming same all time.

Comment: The names are strings not integers.
If you see it with string eyes, it is correct as the first answer implies.
You look at the string as it should be an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort file names "as the Finder does", use `localizedStandardCompare`. In particular, numbers in the strings are sorted according to their numeric value:

```
NSArray *files = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"file10.format", @"file2.format", @"file1.format", nil];
NSArray *sorted = [files sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
```

Output:

```
2012-11-05 11:38:55.474 test77[533:403] (
    "file1.format",
    "file2.format",
    "file10.format"
)
```

Comment: This is also giving same result not the result as your output shows. :(

Comment: @Abhinav: Strange. I have tested this in the iOS Simulator and on a iPhone device. The output is exactly the output from my code.

Comment: @Abhinav: Perhaps you can show your code how the array is sorted.

Comment: i am really sorry.actually i made a silly mistake.your code was right and working perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with the regular string sorting sequence, then you should consider renaming your files. `file00001.format`, `file00002.format` and so on. In that case `file00010.format` follows `file00009.format` and `file00011.format` comes next

Comment: I can do that but actually i have to show same names of file to users and for that it would be little bit unreadable.

Comment: Well, then you could sort the array using an NSSortDescriptor which uses a custom selector to determine the comparision result. This, your own comparison selector (some method) would extract the numeirc element of the file name and return the comparison result of the corresonding number objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working correctly.

```
file10.format
```

Comes before

```
file2.format
```

because the character `0` is seen as less than the character `.` which it's being compared to (both characters are in the same place in their respective file names.

In fact, back in the day, before you young people with your fancy graphical operating systems, this is how the filesystem sorted files too. </old man rant>

Comment: Thanks Brian Willis but Then what should I do so that it come in desired format like 1,2,3 so on? and what about 11,12 and others. Its just taking all 1 collectively and then 2 and so on.

Comment: You could add leading zeroes to the filenames, so `file2.format` would become `file02.format`.

Comment: I got your reason but still my problem is same.What should I do so that this can come in readable format like numbers.

Comment: This can be tricky. Here's a good Stack Overflow question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849911/sorting-a-nsarray