# Why is numerically sorting array of string so much slower than literal search?

Tags: objective-c, performance

We have a number of objects with titles and we want to sort them based on their titles. If we use the default search method:

```
NSArray *sortedObjects = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:
               ^NSComparisonResult(Object* a, Object* b)
               {
                   return [a.title compare:b.title];
               }];
```

It works fine, however, the results looks a bit weird if there are numbers in titles. For example, it will give us an array as the following: "Title 1" < "Title 10" < "Title 2" < ... What really want is: "Title 1" < "Title 2" < "Title 10" < ... Therefore, we switch to `NSNumericSearch` which gives us exactly what we are looking for.

```
NSArray *sortedObjects = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:
            ^NSComparisonResult(Object* a, Object* b)
             {
                  return [a.title compare:b.title options:NSNumericSearch];
             }];
```

Then we run into a big performance issue. We did some profiling and notice that the second method is about 35 times slower than the first one.

**What is it that making numerally searching so much slower? Do you have any recommendations upon how to get numerically sorted results faster?**

Thanks~

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think what you've got here is truly a numerical search. I believe it would be that if your strings looked like "1", "10", etc., but if setting your search to numerical works as you expect (aside from the performance) I would expect the performance is because the engine must do a _lot_ of parsing on this data.

Comment: How's the performance for your data set if you sort alphabetically, and then again using `NSNumericSearch`?

Comment: Is it possible to change the titles to `title 01` etc (do you need more than 99?)? Later, when it's time to display the titles, you could remove the leading '0' again.

Comment: Well, the numeric search either has to perform a string-to-number conversion upon each comparison, or it has to resort from simple lexicographic ordering to something more complex. I would absolutely expect the second method to be slower.

Comment: @mah, thanks for the comments. I have double checked. It is working as expected. Moreover, this is documented by Apple as well: **Numeric comparison only applies to the numerals in the string, not other characters that would have meaning in a true number such as a negative sign or a decimal point.** (reference [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Search_and_Comparison_Options)).

Comment: @AaronBrager, I have tried applying alphabetically search before then numeric search. The result is numeric search becomes much faster. This also leads me to find an answer to the problem. Thanks a lot. I will post a description shortly.

Comment: @ott--, this is actually an interesting idea. However, all these data are coming from the user. Therefore, I cannot customize them as *title 001*, *title 002* and etc.

Comment: I wonder how big your object already. is. Maybe you add a member sortTitle, where you modfy the number?

Comment: @ott--, the object is big. There are a lot of other fields as well.  Sometimes with even photos attached to them.  Yay, but adding sortTitle is a valid idea as well. However, I just notice that the reason why the alphabetic search is faster is because the data set is somehow pre-sorted. Therefore, adding a sortTitle may not be needed. And also, what `NSNumericSearch` really does is parsing the string and extract the numbers in it. I don't think I can really write a parser that is more efficient than the one apple has. But anyway, thanks~

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13229892/643383, except the 'why' question you're asking is different.

Comment: @ott--, we also don't know what will be the biggest numbers in the titles. Therefore, it is hard for us to decide how many number of zeros we should pad in front of the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you have any recommendations upon how to get numerically sorted results faster?

The solution that you should really be using is described in [Sorting is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13229892/643383), i.e. use [`-localizedStandardCompare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedStandardCompare:) to sort your strings. That method will sort strings the way a user would typically expect to see them:

```
file1
file2
file3
...
file10
file11
```

From the docs:

> This method should be used whenever file names or other strings are
>   presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is
>   appropriate. The exact sorting behavior of this method is different
>   under different locales and may be changed in future releases.

It's a good bet that this solution will be both faster and more correct than your current solution. Using `NSNumericSearch` runs the risk of ignoring differences in the non-numeric parts of the string, so that e.g. "foo1" appears before "bar2".

Comment: Thanks, like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I may have misled a lot of you guys there.

The reason why my numerical search is slower is because that the data set I get is *almost* sorted alphabetically. Therefore, I believe whatever search algorithm that [`sortedArrayUsingComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator:) is using has already taken this into consideration. This is the reason why using `[a.title compare:b.title]` is faster then `[a.title compare:b.title options:NSNumericSearch]`. However, it is not alway faster.

Here is a bit of profiling I did with our data set. *Literal search* is slower than *numeric search*. And with localizedStandardCompare, it seems to be even faster.  The result is generated with relatively random data set of 21812 objects.

[image]

Comment: Is there some compiler optimization at work? The [result looks totally different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4umeO.png) with my [random set of data](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb9n1.png). (using the same 100,000 objects for all five tests)

Comment: Or I guess your random data set is not random in its order. Might have misread that...